# wrong result for arc length using scipy

Tags: python, math, scipy

I'm trying to derive the length of arbitrary curve.

I start from a simple example, a circle with radius R.  I get a wrong result!

the result seems to differ from the true result by R, which might give some hint to the problem.

the following code:

```
from scipy.integrate import quad
from scipy.misc import derivative
import numpy as np

r = lambda t: 1
x = lambda t: r(t)*np.cos(t)
Dx = lambda t: derivative(x, t)
y = lambda t: r(t)*np.sin(t)
Dy = lambda t: derivative(y, t)

print(quad(lambda t: np.sqrt(Dx(t)**2 + Dy(t)**2), 0, 2*np.pi))
```

results in

```
(5.287118128162912, 5.869880279799524e-14)
```

for R=1, where it should be 2*pi = 6.28...

for R=5 it is

```
(26.435590640814564, 2.9349401398997623e-13)
```

any suggestions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The docstring for `derivative` says `"use a central difference formula with spacing`dx`"`, and the default value for `dx` is 1, which is far too big to expect an accurate approximation of the derivative of your functions.  Try, for example, `dx=1e-8`.

With your code, but with `Dx` and `Dy` changed to

```
In [21]: Dx = lambda t: derivative(x, t, dx=1e-8)

In [22]: Dy = lambda t: derivative(y, t, dx=1e-8)
```

here's what I get:

```
In [23]: print(quad(lambda t: np.sqrt(Dx(t)**2 + Dy(t)**2), 0, 2*np.pi))
(6.283185278344876, 1.7738885483822232e-08)
```

Answer (score 1):

If you implement correctly the derivatives, you get the expected result:

```
from scipy.integrate import quad
from scipy.misc import derivative
import numpy as np

r = lambda t: 1
x = lambda t: r(t)*np.cos(t)
Dx = lambda t: -r(t)*np.sin(t)
y = lambda t: r(t)*np.sin(t)
Dy = lambda t: r(t)*np.cos(t)

print(quad(lambda t: np.sqrt(Dx(t)**2 + Dy(t)**2), 0, 2*np.pi))
```

The mistake comes from the function `derivative` which use a central finite difference formula, as stated by the documentation https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.misc.derivative.html, with a default step size of 1, which is way to much. Usual values for this step size should be of the order `1e-5 to 1e-8`. If you force that, with `derivative(x, t, dx=1e-5)`, your code yields the correct result

Answer (score 0):

My memory could be misleading me, but don't you need a +1 within your np.sqrt() function? That is:

```
print(quad(lambda t: np.sqrt(1 + Dx(t)**2 + Dy(t)**2), 0, 2*np.pi))
```

Comment: The `1` is used for functional definitions where `y` is a function of `x` and the derivative of `y` with respect to `x` is used. This situation is different: parametric equations where both `x` and `y` are functions of `t`, so no `1` should be used here.

Comment: You are correct. Its been too long since I've had to do anything related to arc lengths. I have no idea what the issue with his code could be then.

Answer (score 0):

The derivative function in scipy does not seem to work well with np.cos()

When testing `derivative(np.cos, np.pi / 2)` it returns 0.84147098480789639 on my computer (the actual value should be -1), but I have no idea why

Answer (score 0):

You are mixing `sympy` functions with `numpy` functions, but they are intended for different uses. To get the best out of `sympy`, use its versions of `cos`, `sin`, `pi`, `sqrt`, and so on. If you do that, `sympy` can do more analytically before it needs to drop down to numeric work. After all, `sympy` stands for "symbolic Python."

Here is a pure `sympy` way to get what you want:

```
from sympy import symbols, sqrt, pi, cos, sin, Derivative, integrate

r, t, x, y, Dx, Dy = symbols('r, t, x, y, Dx, Dy')
r = 1
x, y = r * cos(t), r * sin(t)
Dx, Dy = Derivative(x, t).doit(), Derivative(y, t).doit()
print(integrate(sqrt(Dx**2 + Dy**2), (t, 0, 2*pi)))
```

The resulting printout is

```
2*pi
```

which is exactly correct. If you use `r = 5` instead, the printout is `10*pi`, again exactly correct.

If you need a numeric, approximate result, just wrap the expression in `float()` before printing and you get `6.283185307179586` for `r = 1` and `31.41592653589793` for `r = 5`.